# Events similar to document.ready to be used as workaround for issue with Bootstrap in Awesomium.Net

Tags: javascript, .net, twitter-bootstrap-3, awesomium, dom-events

What I am going to ask is a bit entangled. I am working with [Awesomium .NET](http://www.awesomium.com) and stumbled across an issue with Bootstrap (see this [issue report](https://github.com/awesomium/awesomium-pub/issues/87)). Basically the problem is that somehow Bootstrap 'thinks' the window has a small width and does not react on resizes (aka is not responsive). I realized accidentally that bootstrap works correctly when I call `$(document).ready()` on the dev console. So it seems I can use this as a workaround ans simply execute `$(document).ready()` by myself again. My question is now whether this could have any unwanted side-effects. Are there better events I can trigger? (with or without jQuery).

**Update:**

I realized I can execute `$(document).ready()` in the console but

```
var myFunc= function(){$(document).ready()};
muFunc();
```

has no effect. Also putting `$(document).ready()` into `setTimout` has no effect. Only execute the command directly on the dev console has the whished effect. So it seems the workaround is useless. Are there any further ideas?

Comment: If the dev console, but no other place, works, then it's probably a threading issue; you need to issue the event on the correct thread (which you happen to do from the dev console).

Comment: And how would I do this? JavaScript is single-threaded, I can't invoke into another thread. And I really don't see why `setTimout($(document).ready(),10)` should run different to `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.
I don't know if it's going to help you, as I'm generating my own HTML. 
I removed the lang tag in the HTML element and voilá... it worked.
I meant from this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

To this:

```
<html>
```

If you are loading an external page you could try doing something like

```
 webbrowser.ExecuteJavascript("$(document).ready(  $('html').removeAttr('lang');   );");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I create my own HTML. Removing the lang attribute had no effect for me.

Comment: I had some other attributes set in the html tag (for using angularJS). Removing all of them indeed makes bootstrap works. Unfortunately I would like to have my angular app to  work on this level in order to also bind the title. Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around I figured out to be working currently:

I found a workaround for the time being. It is not the most elegant way to fix this but it does work.
You need to have a 'load' listener set for your web view. You can do that like this:

```cpp
this->m_WebView->set_load_listener(this);
```

Inside of the event 'OnDocumentReady' you can do the following to force the page to update and realign properly:

```cpp
void YourClassObjectNameHere::OnDocumentReady(Awesomium::WebView* caller, const Awesomium::WebURL& url)
{
    caller->ExecuteJavascript(Awesomium::WSLit("window.scrollTo(0,-1);"), Awesomium::WSLit(""));
}
```

When the page loads it should fix itself. This works for me with the latest C++ build of Awesomium.

Comment: Does not work for .Net. I did not state I was using the .Net version yet. I hoped for a general workaround. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Ah sorry to hear that. It seems to be hit or miss sometimes on C++ either way. But for the most part it does fix the problem. Hoping they plan to upgrade the Chromium version in Awesomium sometime soon since it is a very old version currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a quick and dirty solution, you can put this somewhere...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ready();
});
```

i.e. calling document.ready again, when the document is officially ready. Which can be written nicer as:

```
$(document).ready( $(document).ready );
```

Comment: Your solution does not work. I am playing around to find the right point where I can trigger the ready event. Currently I can only dev console works.

Comment: include it at the bottom of the last file included... if it still doesn't work maybe add a `timeout`?

Comment: Please see my update. Only execution from the dev console seem to have an effect.